# How to query two association tables in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables: `courses` and `students`, and two association tables: `registered_students` and `attended_students`. I am trying to query the two association tables to find the students who registered **and** attended a course. I found answers to how to query one association table, but I have two. I'm quite new to SQLAlchemy, so the complexity of it is beyond me.

Here are my models:

```
class Course(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'courses'
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('topic', 'date', name='topic_date_unique'),)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    topic = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    registered_students = db.relationship('Student', secondary=registrations, lazy='dynamic',
        backref=db.backref('registered_course', lazy='dynamic'))
    attended_students = db.relationship('Student', secondary=attendances, lazy='dynamic',
        backref=db.backref('attended_course', lazy='dynamic'))
        
class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('email', 'phone', name='email_phone_unique'), )
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

registrations = db.Table('registrations', 
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id'), primary_key=True), 
    db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id'), primary_key=True)
)

attendances = db.Table('attendances',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('courses.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I decided to go with a no ORM solution. Maybe it's not the best, but it works for me. If you know how to do it in Flask-SQLAlchemy, please share.

```
def get_registered_and_attended_students_for(course_id):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return cursor.execute(f"""SELECT registrations.student_id FROM registrations INNER JOIN attendances ON registrations.course_id = attendances.course_id 
    WHERE registrations.student_id = attendances.student_id AND attendances.course_id = {course_id}""").fetchall()
```